# Good IR LED for tracking with webcam at high speed from up to 50 feet

Tags: led, sensor, infrared

I'm looking to do some motion tracking on a badminton shuttlecock with a hacked webcam(s) and an IR LED. I went to radioshack and got a few leds but it seems that if i don't point them right at the webcam, it doesn't see them very well if at all. I then noticed that the package said it had a "viewing angle" of 45deg. I'de like to get something that would be both brighter and have a higher "viewing angle". Does such a thing exist? If so where?

Comment: I play badminton too. Out of interest, what are you planning to do? And why IR?

Comment: @wouter-van-ooijen We set up a blacklight badminton course in my buddy's back yard. We have two four foot ballast, one on each pole (4x4s we anchored in the ground). We also got a one inch vinyl tube to wrap the course and filled it with water and the insides of about 10 yellow highlighters. In the dark it looks awesome. I want to try to track the shuttlecock and add sound effects perhaps strobes when certain things happen, like speed or height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify you LEDs part number so absolute comparisons are not possible, but there will be many IR LEDs that meet your spec.

[This link](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?vendor=0&keywords=ir+led+optoelectronics+infrared+emitters) gets you to Digikey's IR LED page and you can then use their filter system to restrict current, radiation angle etc.

The [Everlight IR25-21C -  datasheet here](http://www.everlight.com/datasheets/IR25_21C_TR8_datasheet.pdf) is the widest angle IR LED that they have in stock but they don't show it as available in 1's - but they will; probably sell it few off for more $.
 65 mA max, 160 degree viewing angle, 1.6mm x 3.2mm, 940 nm peak output so not all detectors will work - check camera needs.

A few of these working together should suit your viewing angle needs :-)

[image]

Substantially more powerful LEDs are available if required.

Answer (score 1):

Radioshack are not likely to have a good range of things like this.

For selection go to the big names like Farnell, Mouser, Digikey, RS, etc.
For example I opened Farnell, selected IR emitters (you can also type e.g. "IR LED" in the search box) and got [these results](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202996&Ns=P_ATT_BASE_VALUE_1002356_EN_GB%7C1&locale=en_UK&appliedparametrics=true&getResults=true&suppressRedirect=true&isRedirect=&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202996&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=202996), which I then sorted by viewing angle.
I picked the [OP293A](http://uk.farnell.com/optek-technology/op293a/led-plastic-to-18/dp/1497874) as an example out the list which is pretty cheap, has a higher current than a standard LED at 120mA, and a viewing angle of 120 degrees. There are options going up to 350mA and 200 degrees.

Another solution would be to just use more than one of your current LEDs and angle them as necessary.